# WordPress WPLMS language selector on the FO

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, translation, translate

I am currently building a website using WPLMS (http://themeforest.net/item/wplms-learning-management-system/6780226). The problem I actually encounter is that I need to translate my website and display a language selector on the front office. This theme comes with Visual Composer and BuddyPress, I tried using QTranslate-X but it didn't work with VP (even though i downloaded the QTranslate & Visual Composer extension). Is there a way to do what I want ? Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According [this comment](http://themeforest.net/item/wplms-learning-management-system/6780226/comments?filter=all&site=themeforest.net&term=wpml&utf8=%E2%9C%93#comment_7117907) it seems like WPLMS is compatible with WPML - a multilingual extension for Wordpress. It could be a good call to try it, though if you want to use qTranslate you should provide more information - what is not working.

Comment: I would prefer a free solution but I will probably give it a try. I just tried QTranslate because i saw it was supposed to work with Visual Composer, but when I edit a page with VC I don't get a language selector anywhere to change texts.

Comment: Ah,I think then you should try to use qTranslate shortcodes if there is no language tabs - happens if it's not the standard text editor. Try to use hand coding way then: `<!--en-->content in english<!--:--><!--fr-->content in french<!--:-->`

Comment: So basically I insert these inside my WYSIWYG editors ? In HTML edit mode ? I'm gonna reinstall Q translate and try this, the problem is that removing Qtranslate is a pain, so I hope this works. I'll tell you.

Comment: As far as I remember it should be in HTML mode.